# Swift - Cannot pass user gesture from custom UICollectionViewCell to UITextField inside it

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, becomefirstresponder

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` (let's call it `MyCustomCell`) that has a custom `UITextField` (let's call it `MyCustomField`) inside it that users can add text to. However, it seems no matter what I do, the tap inputs don't get from the `MyCustomCell` to its sub-view `MyCustomField`. Previously, I had this same arrangement, except `MyCustomCell` is a `UITableViewCell`, and *that worked for some reason.*

Right now I had to do a **workaround**, where whenever a cell is tapped, the cell sends a `becomeFirstResponder()` message to the textfield. **However, this doesn't let the user tap on the "clear text" button inside the `MyCustomField`, nor does it let the user move the cursor around in the text field:**

```
// function inside the MyCustomCell, called by the view controller
// whenever it thinks the user tapped on a cell:
func cellTapped()
{
    // this is an instance of MyCustomField:
    input.becomeFirstResponder();
}
```

Is there any way to "pass" the actual gesture to the `MyCustomField` (from either the `MyCustomCell`, or from the the view controller that manages them both)?

**Update:** this is what the view hierarchy looks like for the MyCustomCell (sub-class of UICollectionViewCell):

[image: view hierarchy of MyCustomCell, with the MyCustomField in it]

Comment: Are you setting up your cell/textfield through a storyboard or is it being done entirely through code?

Comment: Have you tried to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to `true` for both `UICollectionViewCell` and `UITextField`?

Comment: @MultiColourPixel - the storyboard is just placeholder with some autoconstraint stuff on how the textfield fits in the cell, and how big the cell is, etc; everything else (setting up the customizations) are in the code in the corresponding Swift files.

Comment: @AlexandreLara - yes, "User Interaction Enabled" is checked in the XIB for both the MyCustomCell and MyCustomField.

Comment: Do you by any chance had a UIView that's covering the textfield, lower on the view hierarchy in the storyboard? Having a simple setup like yours with a custom textfield shouldn't be causing you such an issue. Chances are good something is simply getting in the way and blocking your taps from being passed along to your custom textfield.

Comment: @MultiColourPixel - it shouldn't, as I posted above the updated screenshot of that view hierarchy. I think I will re-create the entire MyCustomCell and then post back if that fixes it. Maybe it's a quirk in the XCode??

Comment: @MultiColourPixel - you are most likely correct. Please see the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help to others who have similar issue: I believe @MultiColourPixel is correct in the comment above that there is a hidden "view" standing between the MyCustomField and MyCustomCell. What I did was:

1. Backed up the .xib and .swift files for the code for `MyCustomCell` and `MyCustomField`.
2. Delete the .xib and .swift files.
3. From the XCode menu, re-create the .swift file -- and make sure you **check the "create XIB" as well** when you create the .swift file / class that is subclass of the `UICollectionViewCell`.
4. Copy paste the old xib / swift contents into the new xib / swift.
5. It should work, without needing to explicitly send `becomeFirstResponder()` to the `MyCustomField`.